# Unbind event on click of a table row not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a table and a spinner, when a row of the table is doucle clicked, i want to add one to the value of the spinner and execute function x, in the other hand, the spinner has the event change, when it changes, i want to execute function y. I have this:

```
$(spinner).spinner({ 
      change: function( event, ui ) {
          alert("y");
      }
}).val(0);  

$('td#row').dblclick(function(event){
        $(spinner).spinner("value");
        $(spinner).spinner("value", value + 1);
        alert("x");
    }
```

The problem is when i double click the table, both functions are called (function x and y), how can i cancel the change event of the spinner? i tried this:

```
$(spinner).spinner("value", value + 1).unbind("change");
```

Also, i tried the `undelegate() event.stopPropagation() event.stopImmediatePropagation()` methods, but nothing works, any idea?

Comment: The spinner doesn't have a `change` event. It's just a special method that's called when you change its value. So there's no way to "unbind" it

Comment: Yes, it has one: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change

Comment: Sorry, that's a jQuery UI event, not a real `event`. Like I said, you can't bind to it or unbind it...you just specify what to happen when an internal "change" event is called.

Comment: The `event` is "spinchange"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` name is "spinchange", so you can bind or unbind to that event, instead of specifying the `change` option. Try this:

```
function spinChange(event, ui) {
    console.log("AFAF");
}

$("#spinner").spinner().on("spinchange", spinChange);

$("#btn1").on("click", function () {
    var $spinner = $("#spinner"),
        prevValue = $spinner.spinner("value");

    $spinner.off("spinchange", spinChange);
    $spinner.spinner("value", prevValue+1);
    $spinner.on("spinchange", spinChange);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5cL8G/2/

Notice how clicking the button doesn't log anything in the console, but manually changing the value (and unfocusing) does.